# how limit character in a php code?

Tags: php, character

how i can limit character to below code?

```html
<li>
    <span>
        <a href='{link}' target='_blank' style='font-weight:bold'>{title}</a>
    </span>
    <span style='font-size:xx-small;float:left'> {date_gap}:{sitetitle}</span>
</li>
```

i want limit character to 10character

thanks

Comment: substr(0,10, $string)

Comment: I don't see any PHP code.

Comment: where i hould use 
 
substr(0,10, $string)
please use a example

Comment: what templating engine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To limit the size of a string, do the following:

```
substr(0,10, $string)
```

With the $string being the string you want to limit (and the first and second numbers the beginning and end points of your limitation).

Remember that it has to be in PHP code. Your snippet didn't have any. Use the tags `<?php ?>`

If you want to limit the number of characters in the word banana, for example, you must first assign the string "banana" to a variable.

```
$string = "banana"
```

And then use the function above.

```
substr(0, 5, $string);
```

The result will be the string "banan".

Answer (score 0):

I think this is smarty if it is smarty use the below code

```
 <li>
 <span>
     <a href='{link}' target='_blank' style='font-weight:bold'>{title|truncate:10}</a>
  </span>
<span style='font-size:xx-small;float:left'> {date_gap}:{sitetitle|truncate:10}</span>
</li>
```